# Python adding additional column in 4th dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My current parameter array `a_par_expand` has the shape (3124, 18, 3201, 7) and I want to add an additional column in the 4th 'dimension' to get a new Parameter array `X_trial` with the shape (3124, 18, 3201, 8). The parameter being added `a_T_trial` has been reshaped to be shape (3124, 18, 3201, 1).

I have attempted
`X_trial = np.concatenate((a_par_expand, a_T_trial), axis=2)`

But I get
`ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 3, the array at index 0 has size 7 and the array at index 1 has size 1`

I have also tried to do numpy.vstack, but it still complains that the dimensions don't match exactly.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Why `axis=2`?  Shouldn't it be `axis=3`?

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the issue (^^;)